# Wrapping around window.console

Tags: javascript, logging

I'm working on an old application written in JavaScript. It's absolutely littered with console.* messages some of which are useful for development purposes.

At the very least I'd like to switch these off when a production flag is set. I would also like to stub off any unsupported console methods (trace on IE for example). Note: Assume that we will always have ES5 support.

Concerns:

1. I call into the initializer as soon as the constructor is instantiated. I like the idea of having a separate initializer method because it can be swapped out. I don't however like the idea that subsequent calls can be made. Any thoughts on this? I've seen it used a lot in Backbone's source.
2. As you can see I've tried to keep the production flag separate from the general 'enabled' flag. When in production I noop all of the methods instead of wrapping them (or nooping them if unsupported). Perhaps there's a better way of catching all calls to console (like a jasmine style spy) in production?
3. My hope with wrapping each supported method was to have a way of injecting pre-conditions/formatting before it's fired off. I also use this as an opportunity to check flags like enable. Is this over-contrived?

```
var Logger = function () {
    this._methods = [
        'assert', 'clear', 'count', 'debug', 'dir', 'dirxml',
        'error', 'exception', 'group', 'groupCollapsed', 'groupEnd',
        'info', 'log', 'markTimeline', 'profile', 'profiles',
        'profileEnd', 'show', 'table', 'time', 'timeEnd',
        'timeline', 'timelineEnd', 'timeStamp', 'trace', 'warn'
    ];

    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
};

var console = window.console, p = Logger.prototype;

p.initialize = function (options) {
    var noop = function () {};

    this.options = options || {};

    this._enabled = !this.options.production;

    this._methods.forEach(function (method) {
        if (this.options.production) {
            this[method] = noop;
        } else {
            this[method] = console[method] ? this._wrap(method) : noop;
        }
    }.bind(this));
};

p._wrap = function (method) {
    return function () {
        if (this._enabled) {
            return console[method].apply(console, arguments);
        }

        return false;
    };
};

p.enable = function () {
    if (!this.options.production) {
        this._enabled = true;
    }
};

p.disable = function () {
    this._enabled = false;
};
```

Comment: Did you tested if `(function(){return this})().console` and `''.search.constructor('return this').call().console` return your fake `console` instance?

Comment: I would wrap your whole code into this: `(function(){window,undefined){'use strict';[...code here...]})(window);` (on the function call, you can use one of my methods on the other comment to return the `window` object instead). This will protect your code from external variables and other things that people might try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting question,

I spent a bit of time coding different approaches before writing this. Initially I just was going to point to my [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6768048/7602) but then I saw you have some more requirements that are not met.

**Concern #1**

I dislike libraries where I **have** to initialize stuff outside of the constructor, the constructor should initialize an object so that it is usable! Why give me a half baked object that I cannot use? The idea of being able to swap out a separate initializer is typical [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).

**Concern #2**

In my mind, the caller should decide whether to enable or disable (possibly based on a production flag or not), for your code to take care of both concerns independantly seems overkill.

**Concern #3**

It seems over-contrived to me ;)

I did like though the idea of fool-proofing all `console` methods for an ancient legacy code base, and kept that with 2 simple methods to turn of or on all output in my approach:

```
function logController(){

  var methods = [
    'assert', 'clear', 'count', 'debug', 'dir', 'dirxml',
    'error', 'exception', 'group', 'groupCollapsed', 'groupEnd',
    'info', 'log', 'markTimeline', 'profile', 'profiles',
    'profileEnd', 'show', 'table', 'time', 'timeEnd',
    'timeline', 'timelineEnd', 'timeStamp', 'trace', 'warn'
  ];
  //The one acceptable time we can pollute the global namespace ;]
  console = console || {};

  function stop(){
    var _method;
    methods.forEach( function (method){
      _method = '_' + method;
      console[_method] = console[_method] || console[method];  
      console[ method] = function noLog(){};
    });
  }

  function start(){
    var _method;
    methods.forEach( function (method){
      _method = '_' + method;
      console[method] = console[_method] || console[method] || function noLog(){};
    });    
  }
  start();

  return {
    start: start,
    stop: stop
  };
}

flow = logController();
console.log( 'Normal logging, next is 123' );
console.log(  123 );
console.log( 'Start logging (which is default state), next is 123' );
flow.start();
console.log(  123 );
console.log( 'Stop logging (which is default state), next is "start logging again"' );
flow.stop();
console.log(  123 );
flow.start();
console.log( 'Started logging (which is default state), next is 123' );
console.log(  123 );
```

I will keep the exercise to make this work with AMD/UMD in your capable hands ;)

Comment: I think I understand why you've used an underscore prefix to the method names but sticking to the convention of '_' meaning 'dont use this externally' I've opted to leave that out. Am I missing something? 

In any case I've updated my code. Thanks again.

Comment: In this case, the `_log` etc. functions were indeed not to be used, since those functions cannot be turned off. as for the variable `_method`, I could not find a better name.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my code based upon the review provided by konijn. I've taken the liberty of packaging my code up into a UMD.

```
(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(function () {
            return (root.Logger = factory());
        });
    } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
        module.exports = factory();
    } else {
        root.Logger = factory();
    }
}(this, function () {
```

Added in strict mode as suggested by reviewer.

```
    'use strict';
```

As you can see I've removed the use of '.initialize.apply' in favour of doing init within the constructor:

```
    var Logger = function (options) {
        this._methods = [
            'assert', 'clear', 'count', 'debug', 'dir', 'dirxml', 
            'error', 'exception', 'group', 'groupCollapsed', 'groupEnd', 
            'info', 'log', 'markTimeline', 'profile', 'profiles', 
            'profileEnd', 'show', 'table', 'time', 'timeEnd', 
            'timeline', 'timelineEnd', 'timeStamp', 'trace', 'warn'
        ]; 

        if(options && options.enabled === false) {
            this.disable();
        } else {
            this.enable();
        }
    };

    var noop = function () { return false; }, console = window.console || {};
```

Reduced the code down to 2 simpler methods that either enable or disable the supported console methods by nooping or proxying them. As suggested by the reviewer I've ditched the production flag since I can now pass in an option to enable or disable the console on init.

```
    Logger.prototype.enable = function () {
      this._methods.forEach(function (method) {
            this[method] = console[method] ? console[method] : noop;
      }.bind(this));
    };

    Logger.prototype.disable = function () {
      this._methods.forEach(function (method) {
            this[method] = noop;
      }.bind(this));
    };

    return Logger;
}));
```

Comment: One small amendment. Ensure that your proxied console methods are run in the scope of console.

Comment: this[method] = console[method] ? console[method].bind(console) : noop;